# generic solution for ngdisabled with required field only

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So, I am starting with a requirement of disabling submit button if the required field is not being filled.

```
<form name="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" data-ng-model="model.firstName" name="FirstName" ng-required="true" /><br/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" data-ng-model="model.lastName" name="lastname"  ng-required="true" /><br/>

  <button type="button" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Submit</form>
```

So far so good. However, if there are additional validation field as follow, the above will not work as the requirement is to only disable submit button if the required field is not being filled only regardless of other validation.

```
<form name="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" data-ng-model="model.firstName" name="FirstName" ng-required="true" ng-minLength="5" /><br/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" data-ng-model="model.lastName" name="lastname"  ng-required="true" ng-minLength="3" ng-maxLength="10" /><br/>

  <button type="button" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I could have wrote a bloated solution independently `$watch` the changes of each of the input value for each and every form in controller, but it is tedious and not reusable. What am i expecting is something more generic as follow:

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="!form.$required">Submit</button>
```

Perhaps I missed out something/some existing function that is already available. But I think that to disable submit button until all required field is being filled is something very common for UX/UI.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no easy solution like you have mentioned, You can write a directive including form directive and set a flag in form(by watching the ng-required form fields)
Or, in controller with form have a scope function like

```
function disableSubmit() {
   return form.FirstName.$error.required || form.LastName.$error.required;
}

<button type="button" value="SAVE" ng-disabled="disableSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

Adding the @kubuntu's jsFiddle here.
http://jsfiddle.net/3eqz2/421/

Comment: I don't think that binding a function to ng-disabled works. enableSubmit() will always evaluate to true. http://jsfiddle.net/3eqz2/416/

Comment: @kubuntu, thanks for correcting the fiddle. I have included it in the answer.

Comment: I have update a new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3eqz2/423/ based on what you mention in your reply but it does not work ... The disable button is still enabled even if nothing is being filled